# How to add a non-root ssh-key on Openstack instance using Terraform?

Tags: openstack, terraform, ssh-keys, terraform-provider-openstack

I'm trying to create a Openstack instance using Terraform, and after that, I want to configure the user "ubuntu" with my ssh-key.

So far I'm doing:

terraform-instances.tf

```
resource "openstack_compute_keypair_v2" "tf-keypair" {
  name       = "${var.openstack_keypair}"
  public_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")}"
}

resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "k8s-master" {
  name      = "k8s-master"
  region    = "${var.openstack_region}"
  image_id  = "${var.openstack_image_id}"
  flavor_id = "${var.openstack_flavor_id}"
  key_pair  = "${var.openstack_keypair}"
  depends_on = ["openstack_compute_keypair_v2.tf-keypair"]

  network {
    uuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    name = "public"
  }
  network {
    uuid = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
    name = "private"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "authkeys" {
  depends_on = ["openstack_compute_instance_v2.k8s-master"]
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "authorized_keys"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    }

  connection {
    host        = "${openstack_compute_instance_v2.k8s-master.network.0.fixed_ip_v4}"
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "root"
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
    timeout     = "45s"
    }
}
```

So after run:

```
terraform apply
```

The instance is created, with my ssh-key for the root user, but not with the ubuntu user.

How can I deploy my ssh-key for the ubuntu user?

Comment: Is there a solution for this? I am required to add a non-root user as per the user's choice.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution but **it works**. I'm basically running a script passed with [`user_data`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/serverscom/serverscom/latest/docs/guides/user-data). This allows me to upload multiple public keys that I save as a list of variables.

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "my_instance" {
  name         = "my_instance_name"
  flavor_id    = var.flavor_id_compute
  image_id     = var.image_id
  ...
  security_groups = [var.security_group_name]
  user_data = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "${join("\n", var.ssh_public_keys)}" > /tmp/authorized_keys
    sudo mv /tmp/authorized_keys /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
    sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
    sudo chmod 600 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
    echo "###" > /tmp/authorized_keys
  EOF
}
```

Then in my `variables.tf` file I have:

```
variable "ssh_public_keys" {
  description = "List of SSH public keys"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = [
    "ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxxxxxx user1”,
    "ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxxxxxx user2”,
    # Add more keys as needed
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ansible for that or scp / ssh.
The easiest way is to have SSH access is to let Terraform create the keypair and then use the private key that is stored in the tfstate file.
Terraform snippet to create key pair (which yo have):

```
# create a keypair - note priv key will and should be in state file
resource "openstack_compute_keypair_v2" "keypair" {
    name = "keypair"
}
```

Then one can fish it out like so:

```
jq .resources[].instances[].attributes.private_key terraform.tfstate | awk '{gsub(/\\n/,"\n")}1' | sed -e '/^null/d' -e 's/"//g'  > id_rsa.pem
```

Ansible can then be run with the --key-file option like so:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml playbook.yml --key-file id_rsa.pem
```

Since you say root user access works, you can just run ansible and/or scp to copy the files to the ubuntu user folder and chown 0600 / chmod ubuntu them.

Example:

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  root@192.168.10.10:/home/ubuntu/

ansible 192.168.10.10-host-in-inventory -b --become-user root -m shell -a "chown ubuntu file1 file2 && chmod 0600 file1 file2" -i inventory.yml
```

You probably need to make the inventory file, that you can find in ansible docs.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest going with cloud-init, as there's nothing baked into openstack (and it literally uses cloud-init itself to pre-seed the key).